# .NET types in PowerShell classes

Tags: .net, powershell, class

I am trying to get my head around PowerShell Class best practices, and running into some confusion with a simple class to handle Balloon Tips.

```
Add-Type -assemblyName:System.Drawing
Add-Type -assemblyName:System.Windows.Forms

class PxMessage {
    static [PxMessage] $instance
    static $balloon
    static $defaultIcon

    static [PxMessage] GetInstance($processIcon) {
        if ([PxMessage]::instance -eq $null) {
            [PxMessage]::instance = [PxMessage]::new()
            #[PxMessage]::balloon = [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
            [PxMessage]::balloon = New-Object Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
            [PxMessage]::defaultIcon = $processIcon
        }

        return [PxMessage]::instance
    }

    [Void] SendMessage ([String]$title, [String]$message, [String]$messageIcon) {
        [PxMessage]::balloon.icon = [PxMessage]::defaultIcon
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipTitle = $title
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipText = $message
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipIcon = $messageIcon
        [PxMessage]::balloon.visible = $true 
        [PxMessage]::balloon.ShowBalloonTip(0)
        [PxMessage]::balloon.Dispose
    }
}


$processIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($(Get-Process -id:$PID | Select-Object -expandProperty:path))
$message = [PxMessage]::GetInstance($processIcon)

$message.SendMessage('Title', "$(Get-Date)", 'Info')
```

I have two questions:

1: Why does `[PxMessage]::balloon = New-Object Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` work, but `[PxMessage]::balloon = [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()` does not (`Unable to find type` error)? And does this suggest that using `[Type]::new()` is not yet fully supported, and for consistency sake I am better off using New-Object everywhere? Or at least everywhere in my own Classes?

2: I would like to type my properties & parameters, but I also get `Unable to find type` errors when I type the `$balloon` & `$defaultIcon` properties, or if I type the `$processIcon` parameter in the `GetInstance` method.

Obviously I can type Properties, even with my type being defined. So what is different about the two `[System.Drawing]` & `[System.Windows.Forms]`, and is this a bug, or a feature? And are there other types that behave similarly?

Comment: Using a scripting language to do UI-related things is probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially a race condition!

When PowerShell starts executing a script file, it goes through 3 phases:

- Parsing
- Compilation
- Execution

The *very first thing* that is processed in the *compilation* phase, (so *before* execution even begins) is:

- All `using` statements at top of the script
- Any type definitions - any `class` or `enum` keywords - are compiled separately

So the errors related to resolving the `[Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]` type literal inside the class definition are actually thrown *before* `Add-Type -AssemblyName:System.Windows.Forms` gets a chance to ever run!

Couple of options:

#### Nested scripts

Write a separate loader script that loads the dependency:

```
# loader.ps1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing
. .\scriptWithTypes.ps1
```

```
# scriptWithTypes.ps1
class ClassDependentOnForms
{
  [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]$BalloonTipIcon
}
```

### With modules

With modules it's a bit simpler to manage dependencies ahead of compiling the custom type definitions - just add the assembly names as `RequiredAssemblies` to the module manifest:

```
New-ModuleManifest ... -RootModule moduleWithTypes.psm1 -RequiredAssemblies System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing
```

#### Load from disk with `using assembly ...`

If the required assembly's path is known, you can load it at parse time with a `using assembly` statement:

```
using assembly '.\path\to\System.Drawing.dll'
using assembly '.\path\to\System.Windows.Forms.dll'

class FormsDependentClass
{
  [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]$BallonTipIcon
}
```

For your use case, this last one is not very attractive because you'd need to hardcode the assembly instead of just loading it from the GAC by name.

---

### Why does this occur in the first place?

This behavior might be slightly confusing because everything *else* in PowerShell is just straightforward "one statement at a time"-interpretation.

The reason for this exception is to allow scripts and functions to encapsulate custom parameter types:

```
param(
  [CustomEnumType]$Option
)

begin {
  enum CustomEnumType {
    None
    Option1
    Option2
  }
}

end {
  # do something based on $Option
}
```

Without this preemptive compilation of `CustomEnumType` at parse time, PowerShell would be unable to offer autocompletion and input validation for the `-Option` parameter argument - because it's type would not exist

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I knew I was going to learn something. Classes are definitely forcing me to rethink a LOT of what little I thought I knew. :)
One question, how does ISE vs running as a script play into this? Because switching to Using doesn't solve the issue for me when I run the script using `Run with Powershell`, or a shortcut. In the ISE neither Using nor Add-Type seem to be needed.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, the assembly needs to already have been loaded into the appdomain of the host application - ISE has some dependencies on Windows Forms, so when you run the code in that application, the assembly is already present. To make it work in powershell.exe you would need to run `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; .\scriptWithTypeDefinitions.ps1`

Comment: Hmmm. So, can you include this IN a script, so a single script can be run from a shortcut? Or is it something that must be done first in a session and then the script can be run?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, unless you can statically reference an actual assembly binary on disk, ie `using assembly '.\path\to\copy\of\System.Windows.Forms.dll'`

Comment: Looks like not. That's a bit of a bummer. I guess it is a matter of Classes not being fully implemented yet, and this is one thing that has fallen through the cracks. I would think that running a PS1 with classes in it would be a common thing, but maybe it's more edge case than I realize. I may need to look into implementing this small piece of what I am doing as a function, and then REALLY hope that something more important doesn't fail in a similar way.

Comment: Beyond the very simple use cases (like the enum example in my answer), the expectation is that custom types is something only module authors need - so you'd have the class definition in a `.psm1` (either the root module along with the consuming functions, or a separate sub module imported via `using module ...`), in which case you simply add `System.Windows.Forms` to the `RequiredAssemblies` directive to the module manifest.

Comment: Ah, so as I get more complex, I might find the solution, and it's only at this simple "minimal code" that I have issues. Good to know! Also begs the question, how important is typing the Properties anyway? Seems like good practice, but it works now without that. In any case, off to learn about manifests. Haven't needed them until now. Thanks!

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen How is this formatted in the manifest? I tried `RequiredAssemblies = @('System.Drawing.dll', 'System.Windows.Forms.dll')` and I am still seeing errors. So far I have no found any examples of this setting, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gordon You only need the assembly name when loading from GAC, not the `".dll"` part, so `RequiredAssemblies = @('System.Drawing','System.Windows.Forms')`

Comment: Hmm, seems I have something else wrong too. I'll dig a bit more and see if I can figure out what I have wrong, and post back if I hit a wall. I really should have realized to at least try without the extension. :(

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen OK, I think I am getting somewhere. I was trying to load my module from the same folder as the script with `Using module .\UserMessage_class_script.psm1` and getting the not found errors. I changed that to include the fully qualified path and now the error is about not finding there module in any module directory. Which has me thinking I have to either install my modules in the default directories, or add my directories to the module paths. I had hoped to be able to use a module for my script only, and not actually permanently change the PowerShell environment.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen made some progress, but also realized that this is now really a new question, here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562081/preloading-assemblies-needed-by-a-module-file-manifest-not-working