# Preloading assemblies needed by a module file: manifest not working

Tags: powershell, class, manifest

Given

**UserMessage_class_script.ps1**

```
Using module ".\UserMessage_class_script.psm1"
$processIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($(Get-Process -id:$PID | Select-Object -expandProperty:path))
$message = [PxMessage]::GetInstance($processIcon)
$message.SendMessage('Title', "$(Get-Date)", 'Info')
```

**UserMessage_class_script.psm1**

```
class PxMessage {
    static [PxMessage] $instance
    static [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]$balloon
    static [System.Drawing.icon]$defaultIcon

    static [PxMessage] GetInstance($processIcon) {
        if ([PxMessage]::instance -eq $null) {
            [PxMessage]::instance = [PxMessage]::new()
            [PxMessage]::balloon = [Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
            [PxMessage]::defaultIcon = $processIcon
        }

        return [PxMessage]::instance
    }

    [Void] SendMessage ([String]$title, [String]$message, [String]$messageIcon) {
        [PxMessage]::balloon.icon = [PxMessage]::defaultIcon
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipTitle = $title
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipText = $message
        [PxMessage]::balloon.balloonTipIcon = $messageIcon
        [PxMessage]::balloon.visible = $true 
        [PxMessage]::balloon.ShowBalloonTip(0)
        [PxMessage]::balloon.Dispose
    }
}
```

**UserMessage_class_script.psd1**

```
@{
    RootModule = 'UserMessage_class_script.psm1'
    GUID = '0e53745b-0b05-4bd3-8af2-f1595bca0167'
    RequiredAssemblies = @('System.Drawing', 'System.Windows.Forms')
}
```

And launching UserMessage_class_script.ps1 from a shortcut, not loading and running it in the ISE, my understanding is that the PSD1 file should preload the required assemblies so that when the PSM1 file is loaded by `Using module` in the PS1 file the typed properties of the class in the PSM1 file will not throw errors. However, that is not what I am seeing. Both Properties lines throw an `Unable to find type` error.

Now, if I add

```
using assembly System.Drawing
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
```

before the Using module line in the PS1 file, it all works. Which kind of makes sense, the assemblies are present when the PSM1 file is loaded and the class is compiled, the type is available. This was explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485424/net-types-in-powershell-classes).

But this approach makes the PSM1 file dependent on preparing the environment in the PS1 file, which I THINK I shouldn't need to do. So I assume I am doing something wrong in my use of the manifest file, though for the life of me I can't figure out what.

If I have to, the two Using assembly lines in the main script are really not an issue. But if the PSM1 (or the PSM1 in conjunction with a manifest) can be made self standing, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this and found 2 issues. If you fix that, it should work as intended.

First, your psd1 is probably never loaded. `Using module` requires the **module name** (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-5.1#syntax)), not the psm1 path. If you haven't done so yet, put your module in a folder in one of the valid module locations from `$Env:PSModulePath`. The folder structure should look like this:

```
<module folder>
└───UserMessage_class_script
    └───UserMessage_class_script.psd1
    ├───UserMessage_class_script.psm1
```

And then change the line in `UserMessage_class_script.ps1` to use the module name:

```bsh
using module UserMessage_class_script
```

Secondly, Powershell complained that `ModuleVersion` is required, so add that to your mainfest:

```
@{
    RootModule = 'UserMessage_class_script.psm1'
    ModuleVersion = "1.0.0.0"
    GUID = '0e53745b-0b05-4bd3-8af2-f1595bca0167'
    RequiredAssemblies = @('System.Drawing', 'System.Windows.Forms')
}
```

I followed these steps and was able to make it work. Let me know if it helps or if you have questions.

Comment: OK, so it is as I had feared, that a module must be "Installed" and can't just be loaded from the same folder as the calling script. For a variety of reasons I REALLY don't want to get into modifying the local environment. But it may be that I am limited by PowerShell being what it is. Perhaps I can make it work by just adding my own path to PSModulePath. Some things to play with.
I do wonder, what are the down side to just having the `using assembly` lines? In some ways this would be the easiest solution, assuming no down side I am too inexperienced to imagine.

Comment: @Gordon They can be in the same folder. And yes you can add your path to the PsModulePath. If that's recommendable is for you to decide.

Comment: So, PSM and PSD in the same folder, but it only works if that folder is ALSO in PsModulePath. I'll have to try a few things tomorrow and see what makes the most sense. My use case is a bit, um... off label, so we shall see.