# How to organize powershell class definition

Tags: powershell

I run into issue when executing the following code snippet in `ise` by selecting all and click run:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
class ADUtil
{
    [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup] $Group
}
```

The type [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup] is unknown. If I  execute `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` explicit at first, then I can run the class definition without any error.

Comment: That's correct. PowerShell will parse and attempt to resolve all type references in a class definition before the script starts executing. What is your question? :)

Comment: What is best practice to handle `import-module` if using oop pattern in powershell. I thougth to use `import-module` like importing packages or namespace in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Naturally, you have to import the module first, before using any types contained in it.

To make this more usuable, there are 2 possibilities off the top of my head:

1. If it's a script, you can use the [#Require](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.2) statement:

```
#Require -Module ActiveDirectory
```

2. If you use this in the console frequently, add the import to your [$Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Comment: Is the `import-module` command async? Because it is the first command in my snippet.

Comment: `ise` throws this error if I select all and click run.

Comment: @marsze Synchronous, yes, but [class compilation takes place ahead of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485824/712649)