# Understanding 'Powershell Runtime' and 'PowerShell Compile Time', Optimal method for sharing a class across multiple modules and scripts

Tags: powershell, class, compilation, interpreter, powershell-module

So I finally finished building a class/type but now I am stumped on how to actually deploy it at the places I need. The class is supposed to provide a general purpose type, called Filmcode. I have a number of modules that I want to utilise this type with, as well as some some stand alone scripts.

I have been following the excellent book, Windows PowerShell in action (its actually PowerShell 6) by Bruce Payette and Richard Siddaway. Chapter 19 focuses on classes, and he talks about this importing subject:

> 19.4. Classes, modules, using, and namespaces
>
> Now you know a lot about classes, but you still need to see how they’re organized for use and
> reuse. The fundamental element of reuse is, as always, the PowerShell module. You’ll organize
> your classes into modules and then use those modules in your scripts. The difference comes in
> how you use those modules. This is where another significant difference with classes shows up.
> Whereas most things in PowerShell are resolved at runtime, PowerShell classes are processed at
> compile time. When you want to get all the type-checking benefits that classes provide,
> particularly IntelliSense support, it’s necessary for PowerShell to know about classes ahead of
> runtime.

---

He talks about "most things in PowerShell are resolved at runtime"  and  "PowerShell classes are processed at
compile time". I am so confused by how these terms are being used here.

But PowerShell is a interpreted language and I am using native Powershell code, so what is being compiled? Even then, if I just wanted to follow his guide, When does this "compile time" step occur? Is it when I launch the pwsh.exe process? or when I import the module, such as using it or manually importing it?

I think if I just understood "runtime" and "compile time", as they are being used in this book, and when they occur. I would know how to go about things.

I of course, can just paste the raw code for the class on the bottom of every ".ps1" or ".psm1" but this is not  ideal, I want to learn how to do it the proper way

I searched for these two keywords but turned up with nothing relevant with regards to Powershell. Any insight would be most wellcome.

I am on Powershel 7.4

Comment: Does [this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485424/net-types-in-powershell-classes/64485824#64485824) you understand it better?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Your answer explains a lot, I understand the need for the `using` keyword now. If I have it the right way around, `function get-foo {...}` is  considered "compiling", and actually using the function such as `get-foo ".\hello world.json"` is considered "runtime"/execution. Thanks for pointing me to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fundamentally, ***compilation* in PowerShell** is an ***implementation detail***:

  - Behind the scenes, *on-demand, in-memory-only* compilation occurs.

    - PowerShell v3 introduced compilation for performance optimization, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236617/45375).
    - Custom [`class`es](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes), as well as [`enum`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Enum) introduced in v5, of necessity must be compiled to an (in-memory) .NET assembly in order to act like regular .NET types.
      Note: For brevity, only `class`es are referred to in the remainder of this answer, but everything applies analogously to `enum`s too.
  - (The only exception is if *user code* explicitly creates an *on-disk* assembly from embedded C# code with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-OutputAssembly`.)
- To scripters (users who write PowerShell code), the **distinction that matters** is between ***parse time* and *runtime***:

  - ***Parse-time* processing** refers to the ***static, up-front analysis*** of a piece of PowerShell code, notably to ensure its *syntactic correctness*, to create an intermediate [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) representation of the source code (as discussed in the linked answer), and to compile PowerShell `class` definitions.

    - The design rationale for, technical background on, and constraints around needing to compile PowerShell `class`es *at parse-time* are discussed in the initial post of [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652), which is a meta issue tracking various unresolved custom `class` issues.

      - One benefit is mentioned in the quote in your question: it enables *design-time tools* such as [PSES (PowerShell Editor Services)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices), which notably underlies the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), to provide *IntelliSense* - however, note that *no* attempt is made to flag attempts to use nonexistent members or to pass type-incompatible arguments.
    - Fundamentally, **when *.NET types* are referenced via *type literals* (e.g. `[Foo]`) in the parts of the code that are *relevant at parse time*, these types *must already exist***, i.e. must either already have been compiled in memory (in the case of PowerShell `class`es) or, for .NET types from on-disk .NET assemblies that aren't automatically loaded by PowerShell itself on startup, must already have been loaded.

      - The parse-time-relevant parts all relate to `class` definitions; specifically:

        - Use as the *base* class to derive from or *interface* to implement in a `class` definition (e.g.
          `class Bar : Foo { <# ... #> }`)
        - Use as a *parameter* or *return* type in in a `class` definition (e.g.
          `class Bar { DoSomething([Foo] $foo) { <# ... #> } }`)
      - Note that while using a type literal to type a *parameter* in a script file or script block's *top-level `param(...)` block* (e.g. `param([Foo] $Foo)`) is *in effect* subject to the same must-already-exist requirement, it is technically a *runtime* error.
  - ***Runtime* processing**, i.e. **actual *execution*** occurs afterwards, and  *only if the parse-time stage succeeded*.

---

***Implications* of the above, *limitations* as of PowerShell 7.4**:

- Since [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) calls and even [`#Requires -Modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Requires) directives only execute *at runtime*, a *parse-time* import statement is required in order to make `class` definitions from imported modules available to the caller under *all* circumstances.

  - **[`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#module-syntax)** is the parse-time equivalent of an `Import-Module` call, and it is **the only way to make a module's `class` definitions** - invariably *all* of them - **available to the caller**, including *at parse time*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Unfortunately, the seemingly analogous **[`using assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#assembly-syntax)** statement is - as of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4 - ***not* processed at parse time**. That is, even though it *should be*, it is currently *not* the parse-time equivalent of [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) calls (with `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` or `-AssemblyName`).

  - Therefore, **you can *not* currently use it to reference .NET types from on-disk assemblies so as to use those types in `class` definitions**.
  - Fixing this problem has been green-lit in [GitHub issue #3641](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112) a long time ago, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet (which won't be trivial).
  - There are two additional `using assembly` problems present as of v7.4.0:

    - Inability to use it to load *well-known* assemblies, such as `System.Windows.Forms` - see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856)
    - On Unix-like platforms, the inability to use *relative paths* - see [GitHub issue #20970](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20970)
- Similarly, as of v7.4 you also **cannot refer to a `class` definition *defined in the same file* from `class` definitions**, be it in the context of that *same* class (notably when declaring *interface implementations*, e.g.
  `class Foo : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[Foo] { <# ... #> }`) or in the context of a separate `class` definition in the same file.

  - See [GitHub issue #10669](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10669) and [#20755](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20755#issuecomment-1823080783).

---

<sup>[1] `Import-Module` long predates the v5+ `class` support, and supports exporting only functions, aliases, and variables. `using module` *invariably* exports `class` definitions, and given that PowerShell `class` definitions lack C#-style *access modifiers* such as `private`, invariably exports *all* of them. However, while public .NET types (which is what PowerShell classes invariable are) are normally seen session-wide, and even though `using module` imports a module session-globally too, its `PowerShell` class definitions are visible only to the `using module` caller (and its descendent scopes).</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is everything I was hoping for and then some. So many answers to questions I had in mind. Cheers for this.